# Serialization problem after auto-update

Tags: metabox, theme-options

I am having a problem with WP serialization. To cut a long story short: the problem appeared two months after the site launch. All the strings of text that were stored as a `theme_option` or as a meta box all turned into a letter "A". I guess it happened when WP self-updated to version 3.8.1, but I can't really be sure...

At first - I thought it's a plugin bug. I use Option Tree as a solution to store theme options and meta boxes. I started an issue on the [plugin's repo on github](https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree/issues/289). The author of the plugin hasn't answered yet but after some digging and var_dumping I noticed that not only Option Tree's strings were "A"s but also Contact Form 7's. There on github I've described in more details.

To solve the issue of "A"s of `theme_options` I wrapped the string in the `@unserialize` function - and it worked well. But the meta boxes remain. This solution is a temporary fix.

So I'm at a loss ). You can see the problem online at http://saikoteam.by (mind it's in Russian). The `Warning`s there - are a result of different `foreach` loops getting `string("a")` instead of an array of values.

I will be glad if anyone could point me to the direction of solving the issue.

Comment: Have you been able to replicate the original issue on an install that doesn't have the problem? What does the serialised form look like? Can you post that then what the unserialised form is ( probably just an A but do it anyway for completeness ). What do you think caused it to do this? Could it be that it happened earlier and you only noticed it 2 months later? Has anybody attempted a search replace to change the URL of the site?

Comment: `Have you been able to replicate the original issue on an install that doesn't have the problem?` - no, on my local installation (without the auto-update) everything is good. The only thing that I tried is reinstall WP (deleted all the files and opened `wp-admin/upgrade.php`. Didn't help.

Comment: @TomJNowell, `Could it be that it happened earlier and you only noticed it 2 months later?` I guess not, as I said, the only logical thing that may have caused it is the auto-update.

Comment: @TomJNowell, `What does the serialised form look like?` the Warning comes from a file `form.php` - this is just a template file that I include. In this file I simply retrieve the value of the meta field. While retrieving WP does not seem to run the `maybe_unserialize` function - and simply returns the serialized value. That's what's happening, imo. In case of the theme options I managed to find the needed variable and forced `@unserialize` on it myself. Before that - half of the site was in "a"s ))

Comment: I mean what does the serialised value look like, you can find this by looking in the options table using an SQL client

Comment: If a WordPress upgrade to 3.8.1 broke serialized values we'd have heard of it by now. That release has been out for awhile. There is something peculiar to your site. (Maybe it is the language-- charsets are tricky). Copy your local install-- files and database-- and upgrade that copy. Does that replicate the problem?

Comment: @TomJNowell, here is a `var_dump` of the `get_option( 'option_tree' );`. (http://clip2net.com/s/78iWfI) On this particular project it's a string. On others I run I get an array of values. If I check this string using the `is_serialized` function I get `false`. The only way so far for me is to force the `@unserialize` directly. All the other things (like meta boxes from Contact Form 7) - I have no idea where to find them. But I guess it's a WP problem, not particular plugins... What would you suggest me doing in such a situation?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, yes, thanks for your help, I'll try that. It's worth mentioning that all the other projects I have (all WP 3.8.1 and have Option Tree) do not have this problem, maybe you are right, it's peculiar to Cyrillics

Comment: @skip405 can you take it directly from the database using an SQL client so that it's unprocessed by WordPress? A screenshot PNG file is not something I can copy paste into tools or linters to validate, and I cant do searches on them, it's useless to me, and it's not the original raw value either. Preferably via gist.github.com or another pastebin

Comment: @TomJNowell, there you go, copypasted to https://gist.github.com/skip405/21ee9942af3e24836892

Comment: @TomJNowell, forgot to confirm that it's the direct value of the `option_tree` column in the DB, not the `var_dump`. Sorry for being so slow )

Comment: BTW in WP admin everything shows OK, be it CF7's custom error messages (http://clip2net.com/s/78kl4s) or Option Tree values (http://clip2net.com/s/78knDG). I guess back-end uses the same mechanism (probably `get_option`, I don't know) to retrieve values but does it right.

Comment: then the values in the database are fine, what you put in that gist deserialises fine, your issue lies elsewhere. Can we see the for loop and a vardump of whats being iterated on? It may be that you're doing a foreach on a string and its giving you each individual character

Comment: If I use this tool to check the gist (http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/) I get `Not a valid input` result. And the WP built-in function `var_dump( is_serialized( get_option( 'option_tree' ) ) );` returns `false`. Sorry to repeat, but this serialized string comes out simply because WP does not run `maybe_unserialize` on the value of `get_option` before sending it to the loop. WP decides not to run it because of the `is_serialized` results in `false`. That's why I guess the problem is not in my loop, or in CF7's loop. Sorry if I sound a bit harsh, bear with me ).